# Filter multiplayer games by map or game type?

Tags: halo-5-guardians

Say for example I want to specifically play Strongholds on Plaza or Warzone Firefight on Array.

Is there a way to filter Arena or Warzone games by a specific map or game type?

Answer (score 1):

No. All maps that and game modes on rotation in a playlist aren't currently filterable.